# how to use if/else conditions in css style sheets ? when making a dynamic page and using values from user through php

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement

```
<!-- this is a style sheet -->
body{
    background: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_color'];?>;
    background-image: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_img'];?>;
}
<!-- end style sheet -->
```

In the above style sheet I want only one thing, if user gives background color then it only displays background color,
otherwise if user gives background image then it only display image,
for this i'm using cookies.

user can choose only one option from background image or background color,
please help me. 
thanks.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && (isset($_POST['bgcolor']) || isset($_POST['bgimg'])))
    {
        $bg_color = $_POST['bgcolor'];
        setcookie('bg_color', $bg_color, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
        $bg_img = $_POST['bgimg'];
        setcookie('bg_img', $bg_img, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');

        header("location: page2.php");
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function coloroption() 
        {           
            document.getElementById("bg-color").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("bg-img").disabled = true;
        }   
        function imgoption() 
        {   
            document.getElementById("bg-color").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("bg-img").disabled = false; 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Make your own web page</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        Background option : 
            <input type="radio" name="background" onclick="coloroption() "/>Use Color
            <input type="radio" name="background" onclick="imgoption()"/>Use Image
        </br></br>
        Chose Color : <input type="color" name="bgcolor" id="bg-color"></br></br>
        Input Image : <input type="file" name="bgimg" id="bg-img"></br></br> 

        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit1"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use if/else conditionals in css but what you can do is use js or php to add a class to the body, then use css selectors that match that class and apply the properties that you want.

For example, if the cookie for bg_color exists, add a class of bg-color to the body and then in your css have it setup like this:

```
body.bg-color {
  background: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_color'];?>;
}
body.bg-image {
  background-image: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_img'];?>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using php on stylesheets you can have a conditional

```
<!-- this is a style sheet -->
body{
    <?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['bg_color'])){ 
    ?>
        background: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_color'];?>;
    <?php
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE['bg_img'])){
    ?>
        background-image: <?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_img'];?>;
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
}
<!-- end style sheet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `php` code in any file, the file should have an extension of `.php`. So if you want to set style for the body, write only that part in a php `file` and then include it.

style.php

```
body{
    background: "<?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_color'] ? $_COOKIE['bg_color'] : 'defalue value';?>";
    background-image: "<?php echo $_COOKIE['bg_img'] ? $_COOKIE['bg_img'] : 'default value';?>";
}
```

Also make sure you wrap php with `quotes`.